# multicolumn pandoc slide with ox-pandoc export

Tags: org-mode, pandoc

I was wondering if it would be possible to have a multiple column beamer slide using [ox-pandoc](https://github.com/kawabata/ox-pandoc) in emacs orgmode. Below is the typical syntax for multiple columns, this however does not work if pandoc-export-to-beamer is used.

```
#+TITLE: Title 
#+SUBTITLE: Meetings presentation
#+AUTHOR: Me [fn:NAME: a definition]
#+PANDOC_OPTIONS: number-sections:nil
#+PANDOC_VARIABLES: classoption:"aspectratio=169"
#+PANDOC_VARIABLES: suppress-bibliography:true
#+PANDOC_VARIABLES: lang:en
#+PANDOC_VARIABLES: mainfont:Roboto

* Title

- Hi!

* Two columns

** A block                                           :BMCOL:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_env: ignoreheading
    :BEAMER_col: 0.4
    :END:
    - this slide consists of two columns
    - the first (left) column has no heading and consists of text
    - the second (right) column has an image and is enclosed in an
      @example@ block

** A screenshot :BMCOL:
    :PROPERTIES:
    :BEAMER_col: 0.6
    :BEAMER_env: example
    :END:
```

[image]

This does not work, any other syntax that I am unaware that I can use to try getting multiple columns in a slide?

Comment: Have you tried the LaTeX/Beamer/PDF exporter? Does it work with that? If so, then presumably there is a bug with `ox-pandoc` and you need to report it there.